# How to set multiple values for a Checkbox component in webform with conditionals and keeping the old value

Tags: webform-civicrm, drupal-7

I need to set up a **Webform CiviCRM in Drupal** with a component that can have **multiple values** (checkbox).
But I need to establish its value **based on the value of another field**.

How can I set **multiple values for the Checkbox component using conditionals**?

Also, as the value of this multiple Checkbox depends on the value of another field, I need to keep the former value, and add a new one without removing the previous one.

I have included a screenshot of the conditionals.

[image]

With these conditions, they can only have a unique value and if the user selects more than one option on the field "*Support you are looking for*" the previous value of "*Group(s)*" is removed,
so the last condition which is met is the one that establishes the value of "*Group(s)*".

Any help would very much appreciated.

Comment: If you're hiding the triggered fields from the user, `_webform_submission_presave($node, &$submission) {` should help in modifying the values before the submission is saved. If not - i think its better to implement this in custom js.

Comment: can you tag this Q with D7 or D8 since the approach differs